# Qt OpenGL: Depth Test not working

Tags: qt, opengl

I am working on Qt/openGL and I have some issue to activate my depth buffer.

At every frame, I activate the following states:
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

Plus I checked that the size of my depth buffer is not null (glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS) gives me 24, which is the expected value)
however the depth test is not working and some fragments that should be discarded by depth test are not.

Any idea?

Comment: I guess you could make sure that the Qt version you're using does not use ANGLE, since that seems to lead to depth test issues quite a bit (only if you're on Windows of course).

Comment: You mentioned enabling the depth test and setting its values, but neglected to mention anything about clearing the depth buffer...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers. I use glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) command at every frame before doing my rendering.

Comment: I use Qt 5.3 and I am not sure what ANGLE is. I will check this

Comment: @Zed Windows has had historically bad OpenGL drivers (as in people still use laptops that have DX9 but no OpenGL 2). So people use a library like ANGLE to translate OpenGL calls into Direct3D calls. This can be enabled at compile time in Qt as well.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand, I am supposed to fully recompile Qt without Angle. I will give a shot. Thanks!

Comment: A bad projection matrix can also invalidate the depth test (e.g. zero near-plane), can you include that information in the question?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman QMatrix4x4 l_mat;
 l_mat.perspective(70.f, l_ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f); with l_ratio around 1.7;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so problem fixed!
Here is the method I used if anyone gets the same issue.

I installed GDebugger, and checked that depth buffer was indeed not written.
I exported the openGL current state and here are the states relative to depth test:

```
GL_DEPTH_BIAS=0
GL_DEPTH_BITS=24
GL_DEPTH_CLEAR_VALUE=2147482496
GL_DEPTH_FUNC=GL_LESS
GL_DEPTH_RANGE={0, 1}
GL_DEPTH_SCALE=1
GL_DEPTH_TEST=TRUE
GL_DEPTH_WRITEMASK=FALSE
```

Everything seems okay except GL_DEPTH_WRITEMASK which is false.
I activated it using:

```
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

and everything is working!

EDIT: Actually, the activation of the state must be done at every frame for correct rendering

Comment: Note that the default value for `DEPTH_WRITEMASK` is `TRUE`. So you only need to call `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)` if you previously called `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`.

Comment: True in OpenGL but for some reasons (probably related to QML I would say), the value is false at initialization.

Comment: QtQuick sets this to false during its render pass, when debugging the calls with RenderDoc, its clear that QtQuick will disable it, but then forget to re-enable it. This seems to be an issue regardless of whether I use beginExternalCommands/endExternalCommands or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and setting the GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT in the glClear function solved my problem.